# How would one pip freeze/list all virtualenvs?

Tags: virtualenv, pip, virtualenvwrapper

I have multiple virtualenvs on a single server and I would like to perform 2 operations on all of the virtualenvs.

1. pip freeze
2. pip list --outdated

Is there an automated solution/command that will permit me to perform these pip operations on all the virtualenvs without having to workon/activate/deactivate each virtualenv in turn and run the pip commands ?

I see that as part of virtualenvwrapper there is the [lsvirtualenv](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/command_ref.html#lsvirtualenv) command to list all virtualenvs. But I don't see a solution for running pip commands in each virtualenv.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is long overdue for an answer.  If you directly run the pip script in the `bin` folder of the virtualenv then you don't need to bother with the activate/deactivate dance.  Keeping that in mind I came up with the following off hand bash aliases for a quick and dirty solution that seem to work when I tested them:

```
$ alias freeze-all='find . -type f -perm /ugo+x -regex \'.*/bin/pip$\' -exec echo {} freeze: \; -exec pip freeze \;'
$ alias outdated-all='find . -type f -perm /ugo+x -regex \'.*/bin/pip$\' -exec ehco {} list --outdated \; -exec {} list --outdated\;'
```

Then just run the aliases as `$ freeze-all` or `$ outdated-all`.  You can add these lines (without the $ prompt) to your .bashrc file if you like them and/or hack on it to suit your tastes.  It may lack polish, but it'll get the job done.